# how to parse results from a command in bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to run a command and then check the results for the string "200 OK".

So far, I have the following bash script:

```
for i in $(seq 1 50)
   do
        printf "i is: $i\n"
        RESULTS="$(curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/test/store/widget/123 | grep -ne "200 OK")"
        if [ $RESULTS -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "GET failed with $RESULTS"
                break
        else
                echo "we're good"
        fi

done
```

When I run the above script, I get the following results:

```
i is: 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85  100    85    0     0   3944      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4047
gettest.sh: 8: [: 1:HTTP/1.1: unexpected operator
we're good
i is: 2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85  100    85    0     0   3293      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3400
gettest.sh: 8: [: 1:HTTP/1.1: unexpected operator
we're good
```

The output that I get back from running the curl command once looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 13:21:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"status":pass,"widgetinfo":"{\"widgetname\":\"the best widget\",\"price\":\"100.00\"}"}
```

Based on the above results, I have a few questions:

1. Why does the bash script print the stats about total time, speed etc to get the results from curl?
2. how should I modify the script so that unless the script fails, I only want to see the counter value (i), and a status indicating a pass.  If it fails, I want the script to exit with the details of what was returned by the curl command.
3. why am i getting the error

> gettest.sh: 8: [: 1:HTTP/1.1: unexpected operator?

Any tips?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want curl to print stats use `-s`, by the way you can use `-f` to exit with non zero in case of error 4xx and 5xx.

Valid request:

```
curl -sf example.com -o /dev/null  ; echo $?
0
```

404 not found:

```
curl -sf example.com/test ; echo $?
22
```

And if you want the error message `-S`:

```
curl -sfS example.com/test ; echo $?
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
22
```

From the manual:

```
man curl | grep '\-[Ssf],' -A 3
       -f, --fail
              (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed
              attempts. In normal cases when a HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so  (which  often  also
              describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
--
       -s, --silent
              Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute.

       -S, --show-error
              When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
```

---

So your script could look like this:

```
RESULTS="$(curl -sSfi -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/test/store/widget/123 -o /dev/null 2>&1)"
if [ $RESULTS -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "GET failed with $RESULTS"
        break
else
        echo "we're good"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the http_code using this command

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.wikipedia.org
```

This command prints in the stdout the http code

Answer (score 0):

`RESULTS=$(cmd)` assigns the output of the command to RESULTS, not the value returned by the command.  If you want to check that a particular string appears in the output, it is common to use grep (which will consume the output of command, so it will be unavailable):

```
if cmd | grep -q "some string"; then ...
```

If you want to check the result, just do:

```
if cmd; then echo cmd succeeded ...
else echo cmd failed ...
fi
```

Note that in the latter case, the output of cmd will still be written to the stdout of the script, so you may want to redirect.